# How to create Java project folder structure layout in GIT readme.md

Tags: java, gitlab, readme

Is it possible to create the Project Directory Structure in the `README.md` as below so that this page should update automatically based on the folder `/` file change in the project ? Is this possible to control and modify using Java ? 
Project Directory Structure

```
.
│   pom.xml                                                 # Maven pom file for build and dependencies  
│   README.md                                               # The current readme file  
│  
├───resources                                               # Default resources dir  
│       application.properties                              # set credentials and other project properties  
│  
└───src                                                     
    └───main  
        ├───java                                            # All code for project inside java directory  
        │   └───com  
        │       └───qxxxxxx                                 # com.qxxxxxx namespace  
        │           ├───java                                # Package namespace for pure java tests  
        │           │   └───pages                           # Package for Java test Page Object Models  
        │           │           MainscreenTestPage.java     # Example POM  
        │           │  
        │           └───steps                               # Package namespace for Gherkin/Cucumber step definitions  
        │                   CalcStepsDefs.java              # Step definitions for appiumCalc feature file  
        │                   GoogleStepDefs.java             # Step definitions for webSearch feature file  
        │  
        └───resources                                       # All project specific files here  
            │   assertMessages.properties                   # Property definitions used in qaf library AssertionService class  
            │   log4j.properties                            # Controls all logging to console and log files  
            │  
            ├───android                                     # Additional Android properties. Specified in testng_appium file.  
            │       env.properties                          # Android specific additional environment variables  
            │       mainscreen.loc                          # Android specific object locators for calculator test objects  
            │  
            ├───common                                      # Common resources dir. Set with env.resources in application.properties  
            │       search.loc                              # Common object locators used in webSearch feature file  
            │       testdata.xml                            # Data used in xml scenario in webSearch feature  
            │  
            ├───config                                      # TestNG xml test file directory  
            │       testng_appium.xml                       # TestNG file that runs appiumCalc feature file with @appium tag  
            │       testng_web.xml                          # TestNG file that runs webSearch feature file with @Web tag  
            │  
            ├───data                                        # Data used in data driven tests stored here  
            │       testData.csv                            # csv data file used in csv webSearch scenario  
            │       testData.json                           # example of json data file  
            │       testData.xls                            # example of Excel data file  
            │  
            ├───ios                                         # Addition iOS properties. Specified in testng_appium file.  
            │       env.properties                          # iOS specific additional environment properties  
            │       mainscreen.loc                          # iOS locators for calculator application DOM objects  
            │  
            └───scenarios                                   # Cucumber/Gherkin feature files directory  
                    appiumCalc.feature                      # Appium Calculator app test feature file called by testng_appium xml file  
                    webSearch.feature                       # Web Google Search feature file driven by testng_web xml file
```

Comment: I removed the git tag as it has not relation to git whatsoever.

Comment: I like the idea, don't know of an answer as yet, maybe this should be a change request for the mybatis / maven team (?).